# Dynamic loading of data - vuejs

Tags: import, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have 3 different language files.

```
import { french } from '../fr/data.js';
import { englishUS } from '../US/data.js';
import { englishUK } from '../US/data.js';
```

I load them all in and then just switch in the data I need based on a global language variable. ($root.language)

mounted() {

//switch statement based on $root.language

}

Is there a better way to make this more dynamic and only import the file I need?

Comment: Create a REST endpoint that you can fetch the data dynamically from.

Comment: yes was thinking of axios. Thought I may be missing a better way.

Comment: Depending on the size of your translation files, performanc-wise it might be a wise choice to load them all at build time. Or a really bad one.

Comment: each one is about 40kb, but it all adds up.